# Array being erroneously decomposed into its elements within Powershell pipeline

Tags: arrays, powershell, pipeline

I have a powershell function which is returning a 2 element array, where each element is a string. The return statement of my function returns:

@($source, @destination).

The function is searching a folder for items that need to be renamed, and simply emits them as the original name, destination name hence return @($source, @destination). The source and destiniation are both strings.

However, when I pipe this into a rename-item such as:

**fn | % { rename-item $*[0] $*[1] -whatif }**

this fails because '$_[0]' is being evaluated as the first characher of the first string, instead of the first element of the 2 element array. So the Array is being decomposed into its constituent elements, thereby losing the array.

if I issue this command:
**fn | % { $_.GetType() }**
I get a series of String types returned and not the array that I was expecting. SO something is a miss here and not sure what is happening.

Comment: I've just discovered the solution to this problem, yet another Powershell gotchya; jeez can't you give us a break! Anyway, to prevent the unrolling, instead of returning @($source, @destination), I need to return ,@($source, @destination) to preserve this sub array

Comment: The pipeline always unrolls arrays and collections one level.  Without that, cmdlets like Foreach-Object wouldn't work.  It can't read your mind and know when you wanted it to do that and when you didn't.